# git commit semantic ui as bower_component?

Tags: git, bower, semantic-ui

As I'm looking for best practices, should I git commit bower_components on my repo as I'm working with Semantic UI ?

To go deeper in my thought : I work with integrators team, and I just installed Semantic UI. But, as I'm going deeper, I see that Semantic defines and sets all the site settings, styles, overides, etc. IN bower_components.

As I need to share the job with other people, they should be able to load and share updates.

I'm not fund of splitting it between my /app/assets folder and bower as it should be a big pain when updating Semantic, but as best practices tell to not git bower, I'm a bit stuck in the how-to process.

Also, we are using Gulp on our main App.

Comment: **A rule of thumb**: check only those files into version control that cannot be generated by other makefiles/scripts in the repo: if they either take too long to generate or produce immense amounts of data that you have no reason to track.

Comment: Hi D-side, sorry but i don't understand what you said. The thing is that I just don't want to push bower_components/ but all settings are in this.

Comment: That's just general advice. Overrides should generally reside in your own folders, `bower_components` typically should not be modified by hand at all for ease of upgrades. Various CSS preprocessors offer their own ways of doing this. Semantic UI, AFAIK, uses LESS.